# How to exclude keywords from already filtered list in Powershell

Tags: powershell

from http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2011/06/17/nosql-extracting-keywords-from-powerpoint-using-powershell.aspx

I added an exclusion but the syntax doesn't work:

```
gc "antiinfectiveDrugsLecture.txt" |% {$_.split(" ")} -exclude "the", "this"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't an `-exclude` operator, but you can achieve your result by using the `Where-Object` cmdlet and `-notin`:

```
gc "antiinfectiveDrugsLecture.txt" |% {$_.split(" ")} | Where-Object {$_ -notin "the", "this"}
```

Or if you'd prefer to use the `?` alias for `Where-Object` to make this shorter:

```
gc "antiinfectiveDrugsLecture.txt" |% {$_.split(" ")} |? {$_ -notin "the", "this"}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use an array for the exclude list, and probably use a syntax that allows splitting on multiple characters.

For purposes of an example, I changed gc to a string to make debugging the code easier.  Could easily be changed to an array of strings/etc.

```
$str = "this is a bunch of text and i want to exclude the and this."
$exclude = 'the', 'this'
$str.Split(" .") | ? {$_ -notin $exclude}
```